# Update muitos campos de um model

Tags: php, laravel

Uso o método abaixo para atualizar uma tabela a partir do form:

```
public function postEdit(){
    $produto = Produto::find(Input::get('id'));

    $produto->nome       = Input::get('nome');
    $produto->descricao  = Input::get('descricao');
    $produto->quantidade = Input::get('quantidade');
    $produto->valor      = Input::get('valor');

    $produto->save();

    return redirect()->action('ProdutosController@lista');
}
```

Esse código é eficiente para poucos campos mas imagine um edit numa tabela de dezenas de campos, gostaria de saber se existe algo mais funcional, nos moldes do `update_attributes([:entity])` do Rails.

O Método create abaixo eh bem elegante, se existir algo parecido para update, mata a pau.

```
public function adiciona(){
    Produto::create(Request::all());

    return redirect()
      ->action('ProdutosController@lista')
      ->withInput(Request::only('nome'));
}
```

Agradeço a atenção de todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente você procura o método `update`:

```
public function postEdit($id, Request $request){
    $produto = Produto::findOrFail($id);

    $produto->update($request->all());

    return redirect()->action('ProdutosController@lista');
}
```

Bonus: Melhore a definição da sua rota. Ficar enviando `id` e esperando um `Input::get('id')` sem garantir que esse atributo será passado é passível a erros.

`findOrFail` irá verificar se aquele `id` existe no banco, caso contrario, erro `404` neles.

Aproveite a injeção de métodos do controller e passe ali o que você pode utilizar no método em específico, nesse caso o objeto `$request`. Tente não abusar das Facades, pois existem formas melhores de resolver as coisas...

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido assim:

```
public function update(ProdutoRequest $request, $id){
  $produto = Produto::find($id)->update($request->all());
  return redirect('produtos');
}
```

gmsantos, Obrigado pelo esclarecimento. Vou estudar suas dicas.

Comment: Top! Vi que já está utilizando o Form Request :) Dá pra melhorar ainda mais usando o [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding) e passar direto a instancia de Produto